# Running Android Applications on Smartphone with Lower Versions

Tags: android, eclipse

Hello I am new to Android Programming, I have a doubt, can I run and test all android applications that I am going to create on my HTC phone with ice cream sandwich. I am using android studio and I prefer to test apps on my HTC connecting via USB. My system is very slow while using an emulator it is very difficult to test on emulator

Also 'compile with' API means what, I understand minimum and target sdk in Eclipse..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use your physical device.

But the good practice is to create a range on AVDs from minimal to max Android versions, and to test your app (run tests if you have wrote them) in those AVDs.

Skipping this point will lead to some users dissatisfaction because your app can fail\crash on untested versions. Different Android versions do have some minor differencies in the API and libs behaviour.